# Finding equidistance between two overlapping polygon shapefiles in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, overlapping-features

I have 2 polygons that represent districts from neighboring cites. The Polygons extend 1.5 miles out from the city border. There is an area between the 2 cities where these polygons overlap each other.

Is there a tool that i can input the 2 polygons and have it output them with the borders meeting in the middle between the two cities instead of overlapping?

Comment: Vector solution http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/219997/how-to-get-average-line-of-2-nonparallel-lines/220340#220340

Comment: Raster solution http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/204537/how-to-expand-a-polygon-to-a-minimum-allowable-distance/204542#204542

Answer (score 1):

You could try running "euclidean allocation" tool [link](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/euclidean-allocation.htm) on the original city border polygons, setting the "maximum distance" parameter to 1.5 miles. Vectorize the results if necessary.

Answer (score -1):

The union tool would separate each region (though not in the middle), under the geoprocessing tab. select your two polygons and union will create 3 polygons; 1 for each separate city and a third for the overlapping region.

Otherwise, you could edit each polygon using the editor toolbar to redraw their borders.

Comment: These links might help you: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-fundamentals/creating-a-point-or-vertex-at-the-midpoint-of-two-locations.htm

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/39194/finding-centerline-of-peninsula

Comment: http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000012414